# dc.js not rendering - works in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, html, django, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to get some visualisation set up with dc.js to draw some some data from django.

I was following a tutorial on codeproject.com (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/693841/Making-Dashboards-with-Dc-js-Part-Using-Crossfil) but the graph from it won't render for me in either Firefox or Chrome.

The code is here on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e5gC2/115/
It clearly draws there, and I'm using the exact same css/js files on my server.

My actual source for the .html file I have the graph in is here:

-->
    
         -->

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function print_filter(filter){
        var f=eval(filter);
        if (typeof(f.length) != "undefined") {}else{}
        if (typeof(f.top) != "undefined") {f=f.top(Infinity);}else{}
        if (typeof(f.dimension) != "undefined") {f=f.dimension(function(d) { return "";}).top(Infinity);}else{}
        console.log(filter+"("+f.length+") = "+JSON.stringify(f).replace("[","[\n\t").replace(/}\,/g,"},\n\t").replace("]","\n]"));
        } 

        var hitslineChart = dc.lineChart("#chart-line-hitsperday"); 

        var data = [
    {date: "12/27/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 190, http_302: 100},
    {date: "12/28/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 10, http_302: 100},
    {date: "12/29/2012", http_404: 1, http_200: 300, http_302: 200},
    {date: "12/30/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {date: "12/31/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {date: "01/01/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {date: "01/02/2013", http_404: 1, http_200: 10, http_302: 1},
    {date: "01/03/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {date: "01/04/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {date: "01/05/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {date: "01/06/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 200, http_302: 1},
    {date: "01/07/2013", http_404: 1, http_200: 200, http_302: 100}
    ];

        var ndx = crossfilter(data); 
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;
        data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = Date.parse(d.date);
    d.total= d.http_404+d.http_200+d.http_302;
    });
        var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.date;});
        var hits = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.total;});
        var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].date;
        var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].date;

    hitslineChart.width(500)
                     .height(200)
                 .dimension(dateDim)
                 .group(hits)
                 .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate])); 
        dc.renderAll();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="testgraph" id="testgraph"></div>
    ghfgffghghf
    <ul>
        <!-- {{ passedInContent }} -->
    </ul>
</body>
```

-->

Any idea what's causing this to not render the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript was running before the DOM was ready.